# java plugin 3.9 false positive - always validates to true (squid:S2583)

Tags: sonarqube

Following code leads to a false positive: "!flag is always true" in java 3.9. I have now updated the example code. Sonar says that stilvallid is always false.

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Entity> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    entities.add(new Entity());
    new Test().isMessageInThePast(entities);
}

public boolean isMessageInThePast(List<Entity> entities) {
    Boolean stillValid = false;
    Date now = new Date();
    for (Entity situation : entities) {
        List<Record> situationRecordList = situation.getRecords();
        for (Record situationRecord : situationRecordList) {
            if (situationRecord.getOverallEndTime().after(now)) {
                stillValid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (stillValid) {
        System.out.println("...");
    }
    return !stillValid;
}

static class Entity {
    List<Record> records = new ArrayList<>();

    Entity() {
        records.add(new Record());
    }

    public List<Record> getRecords() { return records; }
}

static class Record {
    Date endTime = new Date(new Date().getTime()+60000);
    public Date getOverallEndTime() { return endTime; }
}
```

Comment: I guess the fragment is incomplete, copy pasting this into a method won't raise an issue. This snippet is most probably surrounded by a try/catch, would it be possible to have more context about this code ? (ideally the entire method)

Comment: The second case is actually correct : lastUpdate !=null is not necessary as || operator is short circuit: 
if lastupdate==null is true, then the if gets executed not the part on the right. if lastupdate==null is false then lastupdate is different from null so lastupdate!=null is always true !

Comment: True. I was looking at the whole expression. Concerning the first One: no Try catch. I'll try to get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem of computing of flow with the nested for each statement. So this is indeed a false positive and should be marked as such in SonarQube UI.

Ticket was created to handle this issue : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1485